# How do you solve for a quadratic sequence that has two variables?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Good day,

Today I found a question related to quadratic sequences, and though I can get the answers by intuition, I don't quite know how to express the mathematical workings.

So here is the question:

"The following is a quadratic sequence. Find x+y."
$$x;18;y;38;51$$

I flipped through the numbers and I realized that x=11 and y=27 so the sequence is 11 ; 18 ; 27 ; 38 ; 51, increasing by 2. (Thus the final answer, x+y=38)

Please could someone teach me how I can express myself or direct me to a website that will do so? Of course, I would appreciate the former much more.

Thanks :D

Comment: You may use [method of differences](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/nextnumb.htm)

Comment: @MaxPayne Hi! Thank you for your response. I looked into the above link but I am still not sure of what you mean by method of differences. Could you explain it in greater detail?

Comment: you can check this site. http://math.cmu.edu/~bkell/21110-2010s/formula.html